# Choose a table field from another table LightSwitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have two tables:

- Products (each has one category)
- Product Categories (each may have many products)

Navigation: Browse products > Add Product (button)

How would I go about making a Details Modal Picker to choose a category?

The Category Option modal doesn't have any categories in them...

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with my current project. This functionality works fine on a new project.